# iTextPDF - Cannot use writeSelectedRows() on a table where an anchor has been inserted

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I am in the process of converting the contents page of my PDF from using page numbers as a hyperlink, to anchors because of a few circumstantial limitations and the linking needs to be more dynamic.

I have omitted outer-loop code, but I am attempting to create a hyperlinked entry in the contents page using the following:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();  

Anchor anchor = new Anchor("page18 link");
anchor.setReference("#page18");
p.add(anchor);
cell.addElement(p);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Once the contents page has been generated (i.e. all the rows have been added), I then use the `writeSelectedRows` on the table:

```
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, PageSize.A4.getWidth()*.05f, PageSize.A4.getHeight()-100, stamper.getOverContent(prevSectionPageCount+currentIndexPage+1));
```

On doing this, I get the following exception:

> Cause Exception was: Error in StamperPDFPlugin. null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAnnotationsImp.addPlainAnnotation(PdfAnnotationsImp.java:125)
>     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.localGoto(PdfDocument.java:2115)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.writeLineToContent(PdfDocument.java:1612)
>     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:1025)    at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)  at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1381)    at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)  at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)  at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:866)  at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(PdfPRow.java:549)    at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:767)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:897)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:845)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:823)
>     at
>   com.ems.rendition.cts.plugin.StamperPDFPlugin.transform(StamperPDFPlugin.java:584)
>     at
>   com.ems.rendition.cts.plugin.StamperPDFPlugin.transform(StamperPDFPlugin.java:328)
>     at
>   com.ems.rendition.cts.plugin.StamperPDFPlugin.executeProfile(StamperPDFPlugin.java:171)

On seeing the stack trace entry for `localGoto`, I took out the line `anchor.setReference("#18.pdf");` and it completed fine without error (but obviously with the absence of the hyperlinks - only plain text).

What is going wrong here? Am I adding the anchor to the cell incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: I tried this in iText 5.5.7 and I couldn't reproduce the problem. Which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie - I'm using 5.4.5. I've just updated my project to grab 5.5.7 out of the repository. I'll re-test using this version

Comment: I've just posted the example I used for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [LinkInPositionedTable](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/LinkInPositionedTable):

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Anchor target = new Anchor("top");
    target.setName("page18");
    document.add(target);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.setTotalWidth(500);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();  
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor("page18 link");
    anchor.setReference("#page18");
    p.add(anchor);
    cell.addElement(p);
    table.addCell(cell);
    table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 700, writer.getDirectContent());
    document.close();
}
```

In this example, I create an anchor with name `page18` (although it just refers to the top of the page) and a reference to that anchor added to a `PdfPTable` using your code snippet.

You can find the result here: [link_in_positioned_table.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/link_in_positioned_table.pdf)

This works for me, when using iText 5.5.7 (which is the most recent version).

Comment: Thanks for the code sample, Bruno. I upgraded the project to use v.5.5.7, tested your code locally and it worked (it also worked locally with v.5.4.5). I then went to test the project build to find that the error is still there. It only seems to have an issue when `setRefference()` is included which is bizarre, as the structure is as above! Do you have any ideas what could potentially cause this? I'm going to try building it up from the bare structure to try and identify where the issue lies.

Comment: From stripping it down, it appears that the canvas argument of `writeSelectedRows()` is what is causing the problem. The only difference between the example and our solution is the use of `stamper.getOverContent()` as opposed to `writer.getDirectContent()`.

Comment: Hi Bruno, there is definitely a problem with `writeSelectedRows()` containing local anchors using `.getOverContent()` as the `canvas`. I may be doing something wrong, but it doesn't look like it. I'll post a new question on StackOverflow for clarity.