# iTextPDF - Unable to use getOverContent() as a paremeter for table.writeSelectedRows() when internal anchors have been added to the table

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I've been trying to create a table of contents which dynamically links to other pages in the PDF using anchors. I've ran into an issue with using `stamper.getOverContent()` as the `canvas` parameter in the method `table.writeSelectedRows()`.

```
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 700, stamper.getOverContent(4));
```

The example below will write a table to page 4 containing an `anchor` destination, and a table to page 8 containing an `anchor` hyperlink which links back to page 4. (Note that I'm using tables for this because it is just a part of what ultimately needs to be achieved).

```
String strFileName = "C:\\link\\to\\existing\\PDF\\document.pdf";

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(strFileName);
FileOutputStream out = new     FileOutputStream("results/tables/link_in_positioned_table.pdf");

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out);
stamper.setRotateContents(true);

//Page 4 table containing destination
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();  
table.setTotalWidth(500);

Anchor target = new Anchor("page 4");
target.setName("page4");
p.add(target);
cell.addElement(p);
table.addCell(cell);
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 700, stamper.getOverContent(4));


//Page 8 table containing link
PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();  
table1.setTotalWidth(500);

Anchor anchor = new Anchor("page4 link");
anchor.setReference("#page4");
p1.add(anchor);
cell1.addElement(p1);
table1.addCell(cell1);
table1.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 700, stamper.getOverContent(8));

stamper.close();
reader.close();
out.close();
```

This works fine if `anchor.setReference();` is an external hyperlink, but if it is internal it returns with the following error:

> at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAnnotationsImp.addPlainAnnotation(PdfAnnotationsImp.java:126)
>     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.localGoto(PdfDocument.java:2178)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.writeLineToContent(PdfDocument.java:1643)
>     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:1162)    at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:994)  at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1541)    at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:1000)     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:994)  at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:982)  at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(PdfPRow.java:583)    at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:833)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:966)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:912)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:891)
>     at
>   com.ems.rendition.cts.plugin.StamperPDFPlugin.createPdf(StamperPDFPlugin.java:1727)
>     at
>   com.ems.rendition.cts.plugin.StamperPDFPlugin.main(StamperPDFPlugin.java:1684)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this an issue?

Note: I asked a similar question here - [iTextPDF - Cannot use writeSelectedRows() on a table where an anchor has been inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633363/itextpdf-cannot-use-writeselectedrows-on-a-table-where-an-anchor-has-been-in?noredirect=1#comment55041525_33633363) which didn't identify that `getOverContent()` was the issue and instead focussed on the actual implementation of the `anchors`.